# Finding derivative of function from the functional equation $f(x+2y)=f(x)+f(2y)+4xy$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

If $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is a differentiable function such that $f(x+2y)=f(x)+f(2y)+4xy$ then
$$1)\ f ' ( 0)=f ' (1)+2\qquad 2)\ f ' (0)=f ' (1)-2\\
3)\ f'(0)=f ' (1)+1 \qquad 4)\ f'(0)=f ' (1)-1$$

---

I tried solving this by assuming the values of $x$ and $y$ to get $1$ and $0$ inside $f$ but that didn't help.

Let $x=0$ and $y=0$. Therefore, $f(0)=f(0)+f(0)+0$, which gives $f(0)=0$. Therefore, $f'(0)=0$.

Now,
$$f'(0)= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$$
$$= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(0)+f(h)+4.0.h/2 -f(0)}{h}$$
$$= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h}$$
Since $f'(0)=0$, $\lim \frac{f(h)}{h} = 0$.

I got stuck here and couldn't think of anything further. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: f(0) = 0 does not imply f'(0) = 0.

Answer (score 3):

Hold $y$ constant and differientiate both sides by $x$. $$f'(x + 2y) = f'(x) + 0 + 4y$$ The answer is now apparent.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)